# Update a single row in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, insert-update

So, I am creating a new table that gets populated from another table. NewTableA.ColA is getting populated from an existing OldTableB.ColB

Source query that populates NewTableA.ColA:

```
SELECT TOP (1) EXEC_END_TIME
FROM CR_STAT_EXECUTION AS cse
WHERE (EXEC_NAME = 'ETL')
ORDER BY EXEC_END_TIME DESC
```

Destination Table (NewTableA.ColA) When scripted out:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [EXEC_END_TIME]
FROM [SSISHelper].[dbo].[ETLTimeCheck]
ORDER BY EXEC_END_TIME DESC
```

The problem I am facing is, I only want to have 1 row in the NewTableA.ColA that updates the current value in the ColA from the other table. I already setup an SSIS job to populate the table every day from OldTableB.ColB... I just couldn't figure out how I can only update 1 row from OldTableB.ColB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use IF condition in SQL:

Example:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EXEC_END_TIME WHERE COLUMNX='xValue') 
BEGIN
   (...update...i guess)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    (...insert...i guess)
END
```

Comment: I am totally confused with your response, can you be more clear or specific?

Comment: Post some data from old table and then the desired new table results.